# Calculus Reference Request

Tags: reference-request

Currently while doing homework I encountered the Witches of Agnesi.  I have done a tiny bit of research.  I was wondering if $y=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ would be one of these witches.  What type of math domain does the study of Witch of Agnesi pertain to? I am completely oblivious to math history a good book/online resource would be nice.  I am in AP Calculus AB in high school if that needed in my question.

Comment: @Moo A book would be better because I was already reading that.

Comment: @Moo Thanks :) 1+

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ (the graph of a "witch of Agnesi") is a decreasing function on $\mathbb{R}^+$, while $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is not, hence $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ cannot be for sure a "witch of Agnesi".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fragment of an answer:

http://aperiodical.com/2014/05/google-doodle-the-witch-of-agnesi/

Notice the several moving dotted lines in this video.  A bunch of propositions in algebra and geometry are lurking in them.